# 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll while deploying Windows Phone 8.1 Hub App to the emulator

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I get this irritating run time error everytime I try to deploy my app on the emumlator named "'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll".

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxR0eQ4XYp86eEZnZDEtRHF0MGc/edit?usp=drivesdk

I have not touched anything in other code files, I have only tried to run the emulator so that i can see my data which I have loaded via the SampleData.json file, which just keeps giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! thanks everyone!

Silly little thing, using a different .json file, but by the same name as it had it in the project, just re-wrote "SampleData.json" in the DataContext, and it worked. Should anyone ever have this issue again.